# Python Google Sheets Formatting

Tags: python, google-sheets

So i have a python script that updates a google sheet with the date and other data corresponding to it. 
Right now, i just add a row with the data i want inside it

```
row = [str(dateIn), outcome, numMap, oppAvg]
index = 2
sheet.insert_row(row, index) # this adds a row to the second row, shifts everything down.
```

When it shows up in the sheet, its just saves it there as a string.

Can i make that specific cell, or even that column to be formatted to a Date? 
I've already tried setting that column to Date in the sheet, then adding the date. Same thing.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. I cannot understand about `specific cell` and `formatted to a Date` of `Can i make that specific cell, or even that column to be formatted to a Date?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? 2. Are you using gspread? From your script, I couldn't understand whether my understanding is correct.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes i am using gspread

so google sheets has the cell format.So it can be a number, date, currency. 

My python program fills the date to a cell, and it selects the cell type automatically. 
Id like the cell type to be a "date" format"

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding:

- You want to put the value of date to a cell of Google Spreadsheet as the date object using gspread.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Modification point:

- In this case, I think that when `value_input_option` is used to the method of `insert_row`, your goal can be achieved.

#### Modified script:

```
row = ["2020/03/26"]
index = 2
sheet.insert_row(row, index, "USER_ENTERED")
```

or

```
row = ["2020/03/26"]
index = 2
sheet.insert_row(row, index, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- In this case, the string value of `"2020/03/26"` is put to a cell of Google Spreadsheet as the date object.
- When `USER_ENTERED` is used, the number is also put as the number.

#### References:

- [insert_row(values, index=1, value_input_option='RAW')](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.insert_row)
- [ValueInputOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption)